# How to detect whether a CircleCI pipeline build was manually triggered?

Tags: build, yaml, pipeline, circleci, cicd

I'm reviewing a CircleCI `config.yml` file where a pipeline parameter has been added for the purpose of detecting whether a build was manually triggered (i.e. via "Trigger Pipeline"):

```
workflows:
  run_tests:
    when:
      and:
        - equal: [true, << pipeline.parameters.manual >>]
        [...]
```

The above means when triggering the pipeline the user needs to add a boolean parameter named "manual" with the value of "true" in order to distinguish it from a build that was automatically triggered from code being pushed to the repository.

Is there an alternate way of doing this that could avoid the user having to enter such a parameter - can the fact a build was manually triggered somehow be detected without this extra annoyance?

Comment: According to the [circle-ci documentation on pipeline values and parameters](https://circleci.com/docs/pipeline-variables/#pipeline-values), there is a `pipeline.trigger_parameters.circleci.event_type` which is available when triggering from a gitlab vcs. It will contain `manual` in the relevant case.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment; if you're using GitHub or Bitbucket, you can configure your conditional statement to use the (built-in) pipeline value `pipeline.trigger_source` (i.e, `- equal: ["api", << pipeline.trigger_source >>]`. This will work because the "Trigger Pipeline" action leverages the CircleCI API to perform the action.

Comment: @yaningo If you use your suggestion the tigger_source is always "webhook" for me. Both for repo changed triggers and manual triggers from the UI. I am using a Bitbucket repo.

Comment: @ReinhardHameeteman, I suspect you're doing something else than manually triggering the pipeline from the UI (via the "Trigger Pipeline" button). Because I just tried (on a Bitbucket project), and an `echo << pipeline.trigger_source >>` does output `api`.